# Monodevelop compiler crash

Tags: c#, macos, compiler-construction, mono

I'm trying to get Mono to work on OSX, but i'm getting a strange error when trying to compile.

I get one error `The compiler appears to have crashed. Check the build output pad for details.`

The ouput is:

> Building: DnsResolver (Debug)
>
> Performing main compilation...
>
> Corlib too old for this runtime.
>   Loaded from: /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/moonlight/2.0/mscorlib.dll
>
> Corlib too old for this runtime.
>   Loaded from: /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/moonlight/2.0/mscorlib.dll
>   Build complete -- 1 error, 0 warnings
>
> --------------------- Færdig ---------------------
>
> Build: 1 error, 0 warnings

I simply cannot find a solution to this Corlib problem. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What runtime version are you targeting?

Comment: From the project options it's showing version 2.0. I also suspect this is the issue.

Comment: Hmm. It seems that i can't even install Moonlight. I'll try to get it up and running.